# Pass argument to a deeply nested function in python

Tags: python, linux

I want to run python task.py --debug in the bash script and now I need to set up "debug" argument for my nested function as follows :

```
main() : 
    call A_1():
        call A_2():
            ... 
                call A_10():
                    if debug : 
                       print("error")
```

where `A_10` is the 10th nested function and I only need debug argument to take effect in `A_10` as shown. Now the brute-force way is to add an argument `debug` from `A_1` to `A_10`. Is there other more elegant way to implement what I need ?

Comment: Do you mean `def A_1():`?

Comment: It looks like they're trying to denote nested calls using `def`-like syntax.

Comment: A quick solution could be to make `debug` a global variable, like a flag that all functions can read

Answer (score 4):

Arguments are available for any part of the script reading `sys.argv`, it doesn't matter if its nested.

Example:

hello.py

```
import sys

def test():
    print(sys.argv)
    if "--debug" in sys.argv:
        print("We're in debug mode.")

def main():
    test()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

If I run `python3 hello.py --debug` it returns:

```
['hello.py', '--debug']
We're in debug mode.
```

Answer (score 2):

Just define the debug as a variable within `main`. That will be enough and it will be within the scope of your nested functions.

```
def main():
    debug = True
    def A_1():
        def A_2():
            def A_10():
                if debug:
                    print("error")
            A_10()
        A_2()
    A_1()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Or also

```
def main():
    def A_1():
        def A_2():
            def A_10():
                if debug:
                    print("error")
            A_10()
        A_2()
    A_1()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    debug = True
    main()
```

In the latter, `debug` is a global variable.

Answer (score 1):

I see two possible approaches, depending on your preferences:

## 1. create an object to manage arguments hierachically

Create an object, eg the Class `Args` at the top level

```py
class Args:
  """store all your arguments here"""
  foo = 42

  class A_10:
    debug = True

# from anywhere in the script at any nested position, call desired function with corresponding args
A_10(debug=Args.A_10.debug)
```

By doing so you can simply call `A_10(debug=Args.A10.debug)`.

Pro:

- no need of globals
- no need to pass down `Args` to all parent functions
- simple
- autocompletion support for class arguments

Con:

- hard coding of variable args in script

## 2. use argparse subcommands

You could kill two (CLI args, hierarchically organized arguments) birds with one stone using argparse subcommands, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#sub-commands

Pro:

- parse CLI arguments
- use subcommands to split up the functionality

Con:

- boilerplate code